# Asp.Net System.Web.Routing Find actual .aspx Page

Tags: asp.net, routes, system.web.routing

I'm using System.Web.Routing to have some better URL's and have come across a problem.  I need to know the actual page that's handling the request.

for example a request comes in as:

```
/basketball/home
```

I need to find the page that handles that request, like:

```
/management/default.aspx
```

I'm only using the System.Web.Routing and not MVC.  I have a handle to the RequestContext that contains some of the route information, but i don't see what i need.

Thanks in advance.

******* UPDATE *******

I was able to use **Context.CurrentHandler** which give me **"ASP.management_default_aspx"**, not exactly the page but enough to get the page name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to use Context.CurrentHandler which give me "ASP.management_default_aspx", not exactly the page but enough to get the page name.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually another simple way to get the actual page:

`String vPath = ((System.Web.Routing.PageRouteHandler)Page.RouteData.RouteHandler).VirtualPath`

Do not forget to check Page.RouteData.RouteHandler is not null - while you are getting the page w/o ASP.Net routing but directly.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not retrieve this from the current HttpContext object?

Perhaps something like this:

```
public string GetCurrentPageName() 
{ 
    string sPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; 
    System.IO.FileInfo oInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(sPath); 
    string sRet = oInfo.Name; 
    return sRet; 
}
```

UPDATE:
Have you tried this article?

[How to: Construct a URL from a Route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668176.aspx)

You should be able to retrieve it back from the Routing table you have constructed.

Comment: This doesn't work because System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath gives me /basketball/home, which doesnt really exist.

Comment: I have tried finding it using the routing table, but there's no public member or accessor for the handler.  That article on constructing a URL from a route only gives the URL, which would be '/basketball/home' and not the aspx page.

Comment: trying one more thing described in that article.

Comment: yeah, the method in that article didn't work either, there isn't a way to get to the .aspx page that i can see.

Comment: Perhaps using reflection you could get the current class, which would map 1:1 to your aspx file

Answer (score 1):

vhinn terrible's answer worked...

```
Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath
```

You just have to remove the initial tilde ("~"), and you're ready to go.

```
var path = Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.Replace("~", String.Empty);
```

I don't know why it was downvoted. Worked for me like a charm.

Comment: I like this solution because it works even in pages not routed. (tested on webforms asp.net 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath
```