# how to get original url from routing in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I use routing in my web forms. for example:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "HomePage", "~/Default.aspx");
```

and I redirect to page with

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("Home");
```

now Is there a function (or solution) in asp.net that will give it route name [Home] (or URL parameters [HomePage]) and return original address (Default.aspx)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just get the full URL:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

and see other .Url properties

see this answer for more examples: [How to get the URL of the current page in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Other questions, however, similar to the previous question: Is there a function that will give it URL parameters (HomePage) and return route name? Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I find my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721392/asp-net-system-web-routing-find-actual-aspx-page

my answer is Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath;